# CSV file creation - robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I want to create csv file which contains:
Header1,Header2,Header3
Value1,Value2,Value3
Value11,Value22,Value33
I also want to dynamically generate the values and append to the file; How can this be achieved in robotframework?

Comment: Did you even searched for a solution before posting? There are several libraries to handle CSV files, go try and use them using the documentation and then if you can't find a solution, and only then, put here your tries and the community will help

Comment: Hi @Claudio, Thanks for taking the time to respond. I am new to robot framework & i did go through the CSV library and String library to do certain things:
I tried the below to create data for file:
Create File
${heading}= "Header1","Header2","Header3";
${value}=  value ["Header1"],value["Header2"];  -->I am not sure how i need to set the value as i want the value to be generated dynamically ; e.g. value["Header1"]= generate random string....
${data} = ${heading} \n ${value}
Create File    ${TEMPDIR}/test.csv  encoding=ISO-8859-1
Append To Csv File  ${TEMPDIR}/test.csv  ${data}

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a number of helper keywords, although it's not clear exactly what you need but you can create a number of header values dynamically by appending to a list based on a specified number of columns as well as two other keywords where the first creates a list of random values based on the header count and another that appends that list of values to a list which would effectively be your row. You can have that also in a for loop which calls the keyword to generate the row values until reaching the specified number of rows.

You can probably do without the csv library if you just convert the list of headers/rows to a comma seperated string and then use standard Append to File keyword to append this string.

So in summary, you could define keywords like the following:

- Generate Header
- Generate Set of Random Rows
- Generate Random Row of Values
- Convert List to Comma Seperated String
- Generate CSV File

You will also need:

The test case itself which calls some of the keywords (Generate Header, Generate Set of Random Rows and Generate CSV File)
In Variable section a defined header count and row count
Libraries (String, Collections and OperatingSystem)

```
*** Settings ***  
Library  String
Library  Collections
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${header_count}  5    # Change this for a different number of headers
${row_count}     20   # Change this for a different number of rows

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: Create CSV With Random Data
    ${header}  Generate Header  ${header_count}
    ${data}  Generate Set of Random Rows  ${header_count}  ${row_count} 
    Generate CSV File  ${header}  ${data}

*** Keywords ***
Generate Header
    [Documentation]  Generate a number of headers, stored in a list with prefix "Header" and Suffixed with the current index of the iteration
    [Arguments]  ${header_count}
    @{header_list}  Create List
    FOR  ${header_num}  IN RANGE  1  ${header_count}+1
        Append To List  ${header_list}  Header${header_num}
    END 
    [Return]  ${header_list}

Generate Set of Random Rows 
    [Documentation]  Takes the header count and row count which is used to create a list of lists containing randomly generated strings
    [Arguments]  ${header_count}  ${row_count}
    @{random_row_list}  Create List
    FOR  ${row}  IN RANGE  0  ${row_count}
        ${values}  Generate Random Row Of Values  ${header_count}
        Append To List  ${random_row_list}  ${values}
    END
    [Return]  ${random_row_list}

Generate Random Row Of Values
    [Documentation]  Takes header count to derive the amount of random strings to append to a list
    [Arguments]  ${header_count}
    @{random_value_list}  Create List
    FOR  ${column}  IN RANGE  0  ${header_count}
        ${value}  Generate Random String
        Append To List  ${random_value_list}  ${value}
    END
    [Return]  ${random_value_list}

Convert List To Comma Seperated String
    [Documentation]  Converts list values to string so they can be appended to csv file
    [Arguments]  ${values}
    ${converted_values}  Evaluate  ", ".join(${values})
    [Return]  ${converted_values}

Generate CSV File
    [Documentation]  Takes header (list of column headers) and data (List containing nested list of row values)
    [Arguments]  ${header}  ${data}
    Create File  test.csv
    ${header_string}  Convert List To Comma Seperated String   ${header}

    # Create the header
    Append To File  test.csv  ${header_string}

    # Append all the values row by row
    FOR  ${row}  IN  @{data}
        ${row_values}  Convert List To Comma Seperated String   ${row}
        Append To File  test.csv  \n${row_values}
    END
```